# Can't start cider REPL on emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, cider

Since I updated cider on my emacs a couple of days ago to CIDER 0.6.0alpha (package: 20140318.1539) I have not been able to run cider-jack-in.

If I try M-x cider-jack-in, I get the following error on the message buffer

```
 Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

If I run the command from a lisp buffer I get the following backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  find-file-name-handler(nil file-remote-p)
  file-remote-p(nil)
  start-file-process-shell-command("nrepl-server" "*nrepl-server*<2>" "lein repl :headless")
  cider-jack-in()
  eval((cider-jack-in) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  ad-Orig-call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Looking at the source in the debugger shows that the code for start-file-process-shell-command calls file-remote-p a couple of times with default-directory as its argument.

Now, I'm not sure if this is useful, since I'm getting way out of my depth here.  But If I try and evaluate default-directory on the source buffer it returns a non-nil value ("/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/").

I tried wiping out my .emacs.d directory and reinstalling cider and clojure mode, but I still get the same problem, and I have not seen any other thread talking about this specific behavior on the cider github page.  So it looks like it's somehow related to my environment.

Any help on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Santi.

Comment: try to open project file first `C-x C-f` (src/abcd/core.clj) and then run `cider-jack-in` `C-c M-j`

Comment: That worked.  Now I'm confused.  If you asked me before your comment whether I had a leiningen project file open when calling cider, I would have said no. I'm almost certain that I could call cider-jack-in while visiting any clojure file.  But then again, I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you need to have an opened file of a leiningen project before calling cider-jack-in. Another option to manually run `lein repl` and connect to it using `cider` function in emacs and specifying host and port.

Comment: it is described here - https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#basic-usage

Comment: I'm cider's maintainer. `cider-jack-in` doesn't actually require a lein project (just the presence of the `lein` command). It seems we introduced a regression when we added the ability to do `cider-jack-in` over tramp. Please, report an issue so I won't forget to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were affected by a regression introduced with the addition of the `cider-jack-in` over `tramp` feature ([commit](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/commit/d928cfcd6d1feb0aad6ae852b952623279115f74)). I've just fixed the problem [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/commit/8fb457d5dd39d22d831f2c5fe23432f53e421b8d).

In future you'd do better to report problems on the project's issue tracker. You're lucky I'm on stackoverflow as well. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!  The reason I didn't open a bug report is because 90% of the time I "find" a bug on somebody else's software, it turns out to be something I'm doing wrong.  That's why I tried asking here first in case there was an easy fix.